# Jquery Ajax issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a tip popup windows for my project. When the user clicks the 'turn on tips' button, the tips windows will show next to some elements.

My problem is that I have elements created from ajax that need to have tips window shown next to them as well and if the user clicks the button BEFORE ajax call, those element won't have tips windows shown because they didn't exist. Are there any suggestions to this problem? Thank a lot.

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? Thanks!

Comment: How do you set tips before any ajax cals are made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `on()` to act as a `delegate` for dynamic elements to bind events.
Below, I am registering `click` events to any event that now or later exists on the `document` with a `class` called `tips`.

```
$(document).on('click','.tips', function(){
   // show tips;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve issues like this by having a function I call `dommods()`. When called, it applies any effects I want to the document, such as tooltips. I simply call it after every change to the DOM, and that solves the problem.